# TOP N join using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Syntax:

List contains a 'Equipamento';
'Equipamento' contains:

- List seguros,
- List ipos,
- List tacografos,
- List DLs,
- List lavagens;

I need to limit the joins, for example: " select top (5) * from lavagens "

Any other ideas?

```
Entity Registo

Class Registo 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Num_Equipamento")
    private Equipamento equipamento;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Registo_ID")
    private List<Seguro> seguros;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Registo_ID")
    private List<IPO> ipos;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Registo_ID")
    private List<Tacografo> tacografos;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Registo_ID")
    private List<DL> DLs;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Registo_ID")
    private List<Lavagem> lavagens;

(...)
// gets/sets
```

```
Class RegistoDAO

public List<Registo> listarTodosParam(){
(...)
TypedQuery<Registo> query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT reg from Registo reg " + 
                " LEFT JOIN reg.equipamento equi " + 
                " LEFT JOIN reg.seguros seg " + 
                " LEFT JOIN reg.ipos ipo " + 
                " LEFT JOIN reg.tacografos tac " + 
                " LEFT JOIN reg.DLs dl " + 
                " LEFT JOIN reg.lavagens lav ", Registo.class);
(...)
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear on what you need? Do you you limit the number of joins or list TOP-5 lavagens with the Registro ID?

Comment: Hi, list TOP-5 lavagens with the Registro ID.
Example:
Registo 1 » (Lavagem 1, Lavagem 2, Lavagem 3)
Registo 2 » (Lavagem 4, Lavagem 5, Lavagem 6, Lavagem 7, Lavagem 8)

Result for Top 2:
Registo 1 » (Lavagem 1, Lavagem 2)
Registo 2 » (Lavagem 4, Lavagem 5)

Comment: got it. If you only want the TOP-5 lavagens, there is no need to use that many joins, you could mace something simple, like `SELECT * FROM Lavagem WHERE registro_id = 'your_id' ORDER BY some_prop DESC Limit 0, 5`.

Now, if you can use _JPA_ you could do `List<Lavagem> findTop5ByRegistroOrderBySomePropDesc(Registo registro);`

Comment: why push on JPA all registo's and after filter?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understood your question. Could you please reformulate it?

Comment: so, father object = Registo, son object = Lavagem (father 1:N son's).
example: 1 father have 10 son's, but i need only top first 5  son's. result: 1 father with 5 son's.